# Passing Information from a child to a parent on an event

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have created a custom matplotlib toolbar, and I'm working on the functions associated with the custom toolbar's buttons. One of the buttons functions will (eventually) return a list position that best represents a user's selected position from a plot. I was having a bit of difficulty making this work in my mind, so I made a simple example (trying to avoid using globals) where a label not associated with the toolbar is updated when the toolbar button is pressed.

```
class TrackPlotToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):

    toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.toolitems if
        t[0] in ('Home', 'Pan', 'Zoom', 'Save')]
    toolitems.append(('Trace', 'Trace Track Position', 'Trace', 'Trace_old'))

    def __init__(self, plotCanvas, frame):
        self.TraceListOld = []
        self.TraceListNew = []
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.__init__(self, plotCanvas, frame)

    def set_message(self, msg):
        pass

    def Trace_old(self):
        gui.infoLabel.text = "abrakadabra"
        gui.infoLabel.update()
        return 1

class gui(Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.grid()
            self.parent = parent
            self.infoLabel = Label(master = self, text = 'magic')
            self.initUI()


        def initUI(self):
            TestPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(TestFig, self)
            TestPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column = 0,\
            row = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 5)    
            TestFrame = Frame(self)
            TestFrame.grid(column = 2, row =6, columnspan = 3)    
            shockToolbar = TrackPlotToolbar(TestPlot,TestFrame)
            shockToolbar.update()
            self.infoLabel.grid(column = 2, row = 7)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = gui(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Am I taking the wrong approach? Is it possible to inquire for new data on an event associated with a class inside of the parent class?

Comment: I don't think it would be terrible to pass your `gui` instance to `TrackPlotToolbar.__init__` and set it as `self.gui`. Then, any of the toolbar buttons can readily access your `gui` instance if needed. The statement that "a label not associated with the toolbar is updated when the toolbar button is pressed" kind of means that the label *is* associated with the toolbar.

Comment: Would what you are mentioning still work if I had multiple toolbars with multiple plots? I'm pretty sure that the answer is yes but I just want to be certain.

Comment: Yup, you're just storing a reference to the relevant frame in your element instances so you can easily access it.